# Printing in Winform Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I have a C#.NET Winform Application, using which, printing of bills etc. would be done.

But the printing would be done by users using a DMP printer.

So is it possible to send the print to a DMP printer in winform application. If yes, then how?

Also, i have a DataGridView in a Form. Now I want to Print that table which is displayed in the gridview. How do i do this? Will I have to use Crystal Reports or else?

Comment: About printing from .NET/C# in general: when we started our first big winforms-CRUD-app I was also concerned about printing. Because I realy don't like crystal reports we bought a 3rd party reporting suite (DevExpress XtraReports in our case, but there are others). I was first reluctant to spend the money, but today I am rather happy I did so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well not sure this answers you well but i would use PDF Sharp or Migra doc to genereate pdf file from your data and print from there, this way i would not have to do Printer DMP settings (I guess)

The easiest and quickest solution is to use the Visual Basic PowerPack's PrintForm control (You can use it in C# projects as well).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb735936.aspx

Just drag the control on to your form then from code call

```
printForm1.Print();
```

This will print whatever is on the form, so just design your report on a form then call that code, and you're done.
look at [Print the form (Visual C #)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa287529.aspx) you can also use VB power Pack

Comment: but what about crystal reports and simple reports which are provided in Visual Studio? can i use them also?

Comment: @Afnan: sir, according to me , an image is sent to the printer when we print in the winforms, am i right? if yes, then when i use DMP printer, then for printing a table of records, it would take hours because DMP is made for RAW printing but not for images

Comment: @Afnan: also, if i use PDF Sharp or Migra doc , then the print would be send as an image or as raw data to the DMP printer?

Comment: @Afnan: also, am not familiar even a bit with Visual Basic, so would i be able to use PowerPack PrintForm control, please help me out with the code, sir

Comment: 1.Yes `crystal reports` is the option but if you are using vs 2010 vs is not there you have to download it

2.you can send raw data to printer if your program must works with `Win32 spooler functions`

3.PDF would be generated if you use `PDF Sharp` or `MigraDoc` but i donot know how PDF is printed(format image or Raw Data).Try printing a pdf from your DMP to see the results if it supports or not

4.`PowerPack` can easily be used in `c#` you donot have to play with VB

Comment: @Afnan: to print from DMP , i have to send the data as raw data ? then only it will print at its normal speed. because windows sends the print as an image.

Comment: @Afnan: please tell me also, that when we print from Laser Printer, like suppose a simple MS Word Document, then as far as i know it is send as an image to the printer. am i right?

Comment: I donot know that sorry googling might end up with results

Answer (score 1):

u can only do code like in C# to print any document or page.

PrintDialog p1= new PrintDialog ()

p1.ShowDialog();

Comment: also, would it work for a DMP printer. it should not send it as an image to the printer, but as raw data, otherwise the DMP printer would take hours to print the data

Answer (score 1):

I would use visual studio's emmbeded control calles "ReportViewer" control.
You can find it under "Reporting" section in the toolbox . 
Please note that you need to have an app that target's framwork 3 and above for you to see this control. 
In this control you can Print to selected printer , export to pdf,word and excel.

Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I do know there's already an accepted answer but I wish to add a new link to a youtube tutorial that i found recently. [Print receipt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToRXCw91r-c)

Cheers.